# Obtaining the user who originated the change event in Vaadin Collaboration Kit when subscribing to changes in a NamedMap within a Topic

Tags: vaadin

I am using Vaadin Collaboration Kit and have subscribed to changes in a NamedMap within a Topic in Vaadin Collaboration Engine. I would like to obtain the user who originated the change event when updates occur in the map.

Here is the code I am using to subscribe to changes in the NamedMap:

```java
CollaborationEngine.getInstance().openTopicConnection(this, "topic",
        localUser, topicConnection -> {
            CollaborationMap formManagerCollaborationMap = topicConnection.getNamedMap("mapvalues");
            formManagerCollaborationMap.subscribe(event -> {
   // How can I obtain the user who originated the change event?
    // I want to access the user who made the change in the map
    // ...
            });
            return null;
        }
);
```

How can I retrieve the user ID who originated the change event? Is there any specific method or property to access this information?

I have tried to use the event, but is of type MapChangeEvent which only has the attributes key:String, oldValue:JsonNode, value:JsonNode. I couldn't find the user information associated with the event

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collaboration Kit does not track that information. If you need to know it, then you can embed it in the value that you store in the map itself.